# Showing that $\inf_{\|x\|=1}\langle Tx,x\rangle$ and $\sup_{\|x\|=1}\langle Tx,x\rangle$ are eigenvalues of $T$ (in particular when they are $0$)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, compact-operators, adjoint-operators

Let $T$ be a compact self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$. I'd already proved that $m=\inf_{\|x\|=1}\langle Tx,x\rangle$ and $M=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\langle Tx,x\rangle$ are elements of $\sigma(T)$ and that $m=\inf\sigma(T)$ and $M=\sup\sigma(T)$. Since $T$ is compact, we have $$\tag{$\star$} \sigma(T)=\{0\}\cup \{\lambda\in\Bbb K:\lambda~\text{is an eigenvalue of}~T\}.$$ I aim to show that $m$ and $M$ are the smallest and highest eigenvalues of $T$, respectively. When $m\neq0$ and $M\neq0$, we are done by $\star$. How can I show that these values are eigenvalues of $T$ when one of them is $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that
$$
          m\|x\|^2 \le \langle Tx,x\rangle \le M\|x\|^2.
$$
Define
$$
       [x,y] = \langle (MI-T)x,y\rangle.
$$
This is a pseudo inner product on $H$ because $\langle (MI-T)x,x\rangle$ is non-negative, but not necessarily strictly positive for $x\ne 0$. As such, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality holds:
$$
          |[x,y]|^2 \le [x,x][y,y].
$$
Let $y=(MI-T)x$:
\begin{align}
        \|(MI-T)x\|^4 &\le [x,x]\langle (MI-T)^2x,(MI-T)x\rangle \\
    &\le [x,x](M-m)\langle(MI-T)x,(MI-T)x\rangle \\
    & = (M-m)[x,x]\|(MI-T)x\|^2.
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
               \|(MI-T)x\|^2 \le (M-m)[x,x].
$$
Suppose there is a sequence of unit vectors $\{ x_n \}$ such that $\langle Tx_n,x_n\rangle \rightarrow M$. Then $[x_n,x_n]\rightarrow 0$, which forces $(MI-T)x_n\rightarrow 0$. By compactness, there is a subsequence $\{ x_{n_k} \}$ such that $\{ Tx_{n_k} \}$ converges. Therefore, assuming $M \ne 0$, it follows that $\{ x_{n_k} \}$ converges to some $x$ because $(MI-T)x_{n_k}\rightarrow 0$,  $Tx_{n_k}$ converges, and $M\ne 0$.
And $\|x\|=1$ because $\|x_n\|=1$. Finally, $(MI-T)x=\lim_n (MI-T)x_{n_k}=0$.

Comment: Why did you assumed $M\neq0$? This is just the case I'm interested in.

Comment: @Filburt : The selfadjoint operator $Tx=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n$ where $\{e_n \}$ is an orthonormal basis has $M=0$, but does not have eigenvalue $0$. You'll notice in the proof where $M=0$ breaks down.

Comment: So... the exercise is incorrect? It ask us to show that $M=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\langle Tx, x\rangle$ is the greatest eigenvalue of a compact self-adjoint operator $T$.

Comment: @Filburt : $0$ is in the spectrum in the example I have given you, but it is not an eigenvalue. So, that makes it an approximate eigenvalue, which is the only other type of spectral point that selfadjoint operators have. $0$ is the only possible approximate eigenvalue for a compact selfadjoint operator.

Comment: This is not what the author meant, I'm sure.  I'll investigate your example. Thanks for be helping me.

Comment: @Filburt : You are welcome.

Comment: You are right, this is a counterexample and, therefore, an answer to my question (although it is located in a comment). I'm accepting your post...